# how to format getdate into YYYYMMDDHHmmSS

Tags: sql-server-2005, getdate

In SQL Server how do I format `getdate()` output into `YYYYMMDDHHmmSS` where `HH` is 24 hour format?

I've got the `YYYYMMDD` done with

```
select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),112)
```

but that is as far as I got.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select replace(
       replace(
       replace(convert(varchar(19), getdate(), 126),
       '-',''),
       'T',''),
       ':','')
```

Answer (score 31):

Just for anyone searching for this functionality that has SQL Server 2012 you can use the FORMAT function:

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') AS 'Custom DateTime'
```

This allows any .NET format strings making it a useful new addition.

Comment: +1 - very helpful. Now you can use all these datetime.tostring formats from the .net framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

Close but not exactly what you are asking for:

```
select CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 126)
```

e.g.

```
2011-09-23T12:18:24.837
```

(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces), ISO8601 without timezone)

Ref: [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

There is no way to specify a custom format with `CONVERT()`. The other option is to perform string manipulation to create in the format you desire.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

select CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 120)
e.g.

2011-09-23 12:18:24 
(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h) ,ODBC canonical).

Hth.

Answer (score 2):

Another option!

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(8), GETDATE(),112) + 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())) + 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(MI,GETDATE())) + 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(SS,GETDATE()));
```

Answer (score 0):

converting datetime that way requires more than one call to convert. Best use for this is in a function that returns a varchar.

```
select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),112) --YYYYMMDD
select CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),108) --HH:MM:SS
```

Put them together like so inside the function

```
DECLARE @result as varchar(20)
set @result = CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),112) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),108)
print @result
```

20131220 13:15:50

As Thinhbk posted you can use `select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),20)` or `select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),120)` to get quite close to what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(8),getdate(),112) + 
case when Len(CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(HH,getdate()))) =1 then '0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(HH,getdate())) else CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(HH,getdate())) end +
case when Len( CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(MI,getdate())) ) =1 then '0' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(MI,getdate())) else CONVERT(nvarchar(2),DATEPART(MI,getdate())) end
```